# Celery: how to customize multiprocessing pool initialization?

Tags: python, celery, python-multiprocessing, python-billiard

I want **processes in the process pool to start with some GPU-allocated 
array** ( allocating the array on request is too time-costly ).

1. Is there a way to customize initialization of the pool s.t. every process in the pool has a GPU-allocated array and only frees the memory when it dies?
2. if the above is possible, then how would a task access the executing thread's GPU tensor allocated at initialization?

I can see that -- from celery's github -- [pefork.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/b2668607c909c61becd151905b4525190c19ff4a/celery/concurrency/prefork.py) defines `process_initializer` function which is used as an initializer to the process pool. I'm planning on editing the source, but I am not sure how to approach this.

thanks